# what is the proper way to use redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I`ve just started to learn redux/toolkit. And I encounter the problem. I read in the documentation of redux that async logic can be processed in midlewares which are created with createAsyncThunk.
So I see two ways how the data can be fetched and pushed to the server. First, you can create reducers that are making changes to the state and fetch or push requests directly from the react component calling dispatch the action and just passing payload that is processed by reducers.
and the second way to use thunks and extra reduces. But when I use them I don't have the logic to put to reducers. I wonder which option to use?

```
const postsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'posts',
    initialState: {
        postsList: [],
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers:{
        addPost: (state, action) => {
            return state.postsList.push(action.payload);
        },
        deletePost: (state, action) => {
            return state.postsList.filter((item, i) => i!== action.id);
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchPosts.pending]: state => {
            state.status = 'loading';
        },
        [fetchPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded';
            state.postsList = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed';
            state.error = action.error.message;
        },
    }
});

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#using-middleware-to-enable-async-logic) is a better way to handle the async operations. You can just leave `reducers` empty if you don't have any actions there. also have  a look at [Async Requests with createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#async-requests-with-createasyncthunk)

Comment: What kind of logic your want to put to reducers?